# Facebook graph API omits some posts from page's wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This is the api request: /116742961694579/feed?limit=336&since=1319843968

It returns a lot of posts from the wall for this page http://www.facebook.com/easbrand

but one is missing, this one: http://www.facebook.com/DanielCWhite/posts/242479269139237

you can see it on EAS's wall (see link above)

Why is it not showing up when we do the api call for the feed for this page?  I also tried 'posts', 'statuses', and many other requests besides 'feed' but it still doesn't show up  (I also tweaked the limit and since params)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that Daniel opted out of the Facebook Platform meaning his posts and info are not available at all on the Facebook development platform.

Comment: it seems unlikely that he opted out of the facebook platform (or, has re-opted-in since 11/14/11), as you can still pull information about him via the graph api : https://graph.facebook.com/DanielCWhite